# I am logged in as admin user but I get a message saying I am not authorised to access the Update or Install pages

Tags: users

I am not able as user 1 to access the 'Extend -> Update' or 'Extend -> Install new module' pages (I can, however, access the 'Extend -> Uninstall' page). This has only started happening in the last few days.The message I get is:

**Access denied**
You are not authorized to access this page.

I am on a Drupal 9.4.8 distro running on a Siteground remote server. This has only started happening in the last few days.

I looked at this page which had some helpful suggestions:

[Not able to access "Updates" page logged in as admin user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227401/not-able-to-access-updates-page-logged-in-as-admin-user/)

I have so far tried:

- setting allow_authorize_operations to True in settings.php,
- rebuilding permissions under "/admin/reports/status/rebuild"
- and clearing cache with drush cr.

None of the above resolved the problem so I am still looking for a solution.

The log messages are:

*Path: /admin/modules/install. Drupal\Core\Http\Exception\CacheableAccessDeniedHttpException: in Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->checkAccess() (line 118 of /[site_root]/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/AccessAwareRouter.php)*.

and:

*Path: /admin/modules/update. Drupal\Core\Http\Exception\CacheableAccessDeniedHttpException: in Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->checkAccess() (line 118 of /[site_root]/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/AccessAwareRouter.php)*.

I would appreciate any help/advice with debugging this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to access "Updates" page logged in as admin user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227401/not-able-to-access-updates-page-logged-in-as-admin-user)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I voted to close this one as a duplicate because we can’t have two identical questions.

Comment: As I stated in the OP, I have looked at the link you posted but it did not resolve the issue I am having. I responded to the post in the link but you replied that I was not answering the question so I deleted my response. I have tried all the suggestions in the post linked to but none of them work for me. I am happy to put the above post under a different question if that helps.

Comment: The answer box on Stack Exchange is for answers only. If you cannot comment it is because you need a certain number of reputation points.

Comment: It is not an "identical" question. It is 'similar' but not "identical". I have already stated that the answers to the other question, although very useful, did not help me to resolve the issue I am having (as I have documented in the body of the question and as I also repeated in the comment above), which is why I am asking here.